# Using source code under LGPL in .NET, converted from JAVA?

Tags: licensing, lgpl

I found one JAVA project useful to our commercial software which is developed using C#. The JAVA project is under LGPL. My understanding is (please correct me if I am wrong) if I use one compiled LGPL library (for example, .dll in Windows), I don't even need to disclaim the license information. But if I need to make some modifications in the source code, I need to include the LGPL license, and make my modification part which uses the library also under LGPL.

Since our software is in .NET, I clearly need to modify from the JAVA source code (starting by converting using Sharpen in Eclipse and then make some manual modification). So my question is, if I convert it to a C# project and compile as a library, and include the license when we are distributing it, is it enough? Do I need to make the source code of the whole new project available (upon request)?

Answer (score 1):

Covering a LGPL java program to C# is creating a derivative work, and the conversion must follow the terms of the lgpl.

So long as you keep a separation between the C# conversion and the rest of your code, you only need to provide source code to the conversion upon request of anyone to whom you give the program to.

(insert standard "I'm not a lawyer, ask your own or check with the java project owner" disclaimer here.)